# reactjs app not run after serve and start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, centos

I just installed `node.js` on my centos 7 server, then install `react`
it successfully created my new react app, after that, I run:

`npm start`

[image]

and or `serve -s build`

[image]

but none of these run in my browser.

> This site can’t be reached

how can I solve this?

Comment: How you created `react` app?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan `create-react-app homer`

Comment: Try using `npx create-react-app homer`. That will use the latest react version.

Comment: I using `yarn` @MuhammadZeeshan whats the different?

Comment: you seem to be confusing npm and yarn commands

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you have sever inside can you try with start debugging of your application

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop npm, if you're using yarn
2. Start the project with command above, inside your project home folder

> yarn start

Take some time to learn commands below:

[image]